# Get the GUID of .proj file using C#

Tags: c#, .net, envdte

I need to get the `GUID` of a `C# .proj` file using C#. I have taken from the `.proj` file like reading the file using XML and getting the tag value.

//XML Tag

```
 <ProjectGuid>{7701AEB4-8549-4FB2-B34C-E71D0B7DE59D}</ProjectGuid>
```

But i need to know is there any specific property in C# to retrieve the existing .proj file GUID, something like this.

//Code

```
 int iIncriment = 0;
 foreach (var objProj in vhaSolution.Projects)
        {
          EnvDTE.Project prj1 = (EnvDTE.Project)objProj;
          iIncriment++;
            if (string.Equals(testProjectName + ".proj", prj1.Name))
                {
                    prj = vhaSolution.Projects.Item(iIncriment);
                }
        }

 string GUID = prj.GetGUID() ???
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use the [IVsHierarchy.GetGuidProperty](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualstudio.shell.interop.ivshierarchy.getguidproperty.aspx) method:

```
var solution = serviceProvider.GetService(typeof(SVsSolution)) as IVsSolution;
IVsHierarchy hierarchy;

solution.GetProjectOfUniqueName(project.FullName, out hierarchy);

if (hierarchy != null)
{
    Guid projectGuid;

    hierarchy.GetGuidProperty(
                VSConstants.VSITEMID_ROOT,
                (int)__VSHPROPID.VSHPROPID_ProjectIDGuid,
                out projectGuid);
}
```

Comment: Where can i find the Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Interop.dll?

Comment: On my machine it's under `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\VSSDK\VisualStudioIntegration\Common\Assemblies\v2.0` directory.

Comment: @SanthoshKumar, you might need to download and install [Visual Studio SDK](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=30668).

Answer (score 0):

A quik and dirty solution would be using [IndexOf](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/k8b1470s%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and [Substring](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/aka44szs%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to find the 
`<ProjectGuid>` and `</ProjectGuid>` string in the .proj-file and extract the content of the tag.

Comment: I'm expecting something like a built-in property which gives me the GUID in exact.